# Why is placeholder not working ie 9 & 8?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Why is placeholder not working in IE (8,9)

I am trying to use placeholder to show some description in input box using the placeholder, and in IE 8 & 9 this is not working. I need to display some text in input box without using any Jquery or javascript. Below is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

I am trying find out the reason.

Comment: Because they don't support it...? And please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting.

Comment: You can almost always assume that, if something isn't working in IE, it's because they don't support it or they do it wrong. You can never trust IE to do anything right if they do it at all.

Answer (score 1):

`placeholder` attribute is not supported by Internet Explorer 9 and lower, but you can use this JavaScript plugin to make it work http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

Answer (score 0):

Not supported by older version of IE. Try placeholder.js